# How do I edit the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable on windows?

Tags: c++, pkg-config

I'm trying to use pkg-config to combine files from ffmpeg into a library so I can use them as such in my program. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get pkg-config to look in another location.

It's worth mentioning that I'm compiling this program into a node API addon for a node project, so I'm using pkg-config from NPM and CMake-js.

Currently, pkg-config looks in `C:/Strawberry/c/lib/pkgconfig`

I want it to look in `C:/ffmpeg/lib/` as well.
I've tried looking for how to do this, but I can only find how to do it on linux.

In the one stackoverflow question which is similar, the link provided is broken: [link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810279/finding-libraries-using-pkg-config-in-windows) , [broken link provided](http://people.freedesktop.org/%7Edbn/pkg-config-guide.html#writing)

Otherwise, I find conflicting info saying pkg-config in windows doesn't consider PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable. I can't test this if I can't find out how to actually do it.

I've also tried copying the ffmpeg folder inside `C:/Strawberry/c/lib/pkgconfig` so it can find it. Even then, it 'cant find libavcodec.pc' despite being located in that folder (albeit several folders deep).

How do I change the environment variable for pkg-config?

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]

Comment: Apologies. I will condense the question down to the answer I need the most.

Comment: pkg-config does not search recursively. also, try to run pkg-config with the debug flag to provide us with more information to work with.

Comment: In the start menu, type "env" and pick the one for editing your user accounts environment variables.